# Insert data in impala table using java

Tags: java, impala

I have copied `mysql` table into `hdfs` using `sqoop` and then created table with same name in `impala` using "`create external table`" command.

Now I have more data to be inserted into `impala` table using `java api` of Impala i.e. `ImpalaService.jar`. Please help me out to insert data using `java api` in the table.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using ImpalaService.jar you can send a single insert statement, something like :**

```
# java -cp ../deps/libthrift-0.9.1.jar:../deps/slf4j.api-1.6.1.jar:./deps/slf4j-simple-.6.1.jar:../jar/ImpalaService.jar:./jar/ImpalaConnectTest.jar org.ImpalaConnectTest.ImpalaConnectTest localhost  21050 "insert into foo values (1,'message 1')"
Result size = 0
#
```

**Then, you can check the result using ImpalaService.jar in the following way:**

```
# java -cp ../deps/libthrift-0.9.1.jar:../deps/slf4j.api-1.6.1.jar:./deps/slf4j-simple-.6.1.jar:../jar/ImpalaService.jar:./jar/ImpalaConnectTest.jar org.ImpalaConnectTest.ImpalaConnectTest localhost  21050 "select * from foo"
Result size = 1
TRow(colVals:[<TColumnValue i32Val:TI32Value(value:1)>, <TColumnValue stringVal:TStringValue(value:message 1)>])
#
```

**or by using Impala-shell:**

```
[root@dub-vcd-vms165 ~]# impala-shell
Starting Impala Shell without Kerberos authentication
Connected to XXXXXX
Server version: impalad version cdh5-1.3.0 RELEASE (build 40e1b62cf0b97f666d084d9509bf9639c575068c)
Welcome to the Impala shell. Press TAB twice to see a list of available commands.

Copyright (c) 2012 Cloudera, Inc. All rights reserved.

(Shell build version: Impala Shell vcdh5-1.3.0 (40e1b62) built on Tue Mar 25 13:46:44 PDT 2014)
[XXXXXX:21000] > select * from foo;
Query: select * from foo
+----+-----------+
| id | msg       |
+----+-----------+
| 1  | message 1 |
+----+-----------+
Returned 3 row(s) in 0.62s
[XXXXXX:21000] >
```

**Note: If you have multiple data to be inserted, then you can modify ImpalaService.jar to a more elaborate solution that executes multiple insert statements by using the arguments to specify a data source that contains all records to be inserted.**

- Ref1: https://github.com/pauldeschacht/impala-java-client
- Ref2: https://github.com/pauldeschacht/impala-java-client/blob/master/test/src/org/ImpalaConnectTest.java